# No me corre AJAX en un servidor pero si en localhost PHP

Tags: php, ajax

he estado haciendo un chat y por alguna razón en localhost me corre perfectamente pero no cuando lo utilizo en un servidor que tengo.
Es un chat, simplemente al apretar enter el mensaje se debe de guardar en la bd pero no lo hace. 
En el caso de que el error sea muy visible por favor explicar a que se debe porque soy mas o menos nuevo en este tema del AJAX jajaja.

El problema simplemente es que no se guarda en la bdd.

ARCHIVO CHAT.PHP

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require '../database.php';


  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, fullname, username, email, password, puntaje,tipo FROM users WHERE id = :id');
    $records->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $user = null;
    if (count($results) > 0) {
      $user = $results;
    }
  }?>
    <div class="cuadroChat">
    <div class="chatbox">
    <h3>Escribe tu mensaje</h3>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <textarea class="txtarea" id="message" name="message" maxlength="250"></textarea>
        </form>
  </div>
  <br>
  <p>**Presiona enter para enviar**</p>  
    </div>
  <div class="chathistory"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            loadChat();
        });

        $('#message').keyup(function(e){
            var message = $(this).val();
            if( e.which == 13 ){
                $.get('ajax.php?action=SendMessage&message='+message, function(response){

                    loadChat();
          $('#message').val('');
                });
            }
        });
        function loadChat()
        {
            $.get('ajax.php?action=getChat', function(response){

                $('.chathistory').html(response);
            });
        }
        setInterval(function(){
            loadChat();
        }, 2000);
    </script>
```

ARCHIVO AJAX.PHP

```
    <?php

include("../database.php");
if( isset($_REQUEST['action']) ){
    switch( $_REQUEST['action'] ){
        case "SendMessage":
            session_start();
            $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO chat SET user=?, message=?");
            $query->execute([$_SESSION['user_id'], $_REQUEST['message']]);
            echo 1;
        break;
        case "getChat":
            $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from chat inner join users on chat.user=users.id order by chat.id desc limit 80");
            $query->execute();
            $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    ?>
    <?php
            $chat = '';
            foreach( $rs as $r ){
                $chat .=  '<div class="siglemessage"><img src="../css/imagenes/escudos/'.$r->equipo.'.png" width="15" height="15"><strong>'.$r->username.':  </strong>'.$r->message.'</div>';
            }
            echo $chat;
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Lo he hecho con ajax para que directamente, una vez que se aprieta enter el mensaje sea visible ya para el usuario receptor.

Comment: No uses $.post() cuando estas pasando parametros por GET url.com?parm=1&param=2. Corrige eso. Por otro lado, recibe las variables en PHP con $_GET['nombre_variable']

Comment: Ademas, acomoda la URL en el metodo $.POST() o $.GET() a 'http://urlservidor.com/ajax.php....'

Comment: y que error te da? puedes verlo en la consola del navegador

Comment: Perdon por tardar en responder, no me habia dado cuenta del post, pero aun no me guarda en bdd. Simplemente no llegan los valores a la consulta